# Use ci-game from Jenkins groovy pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

How can the [Jenkins Continuous Integration Game plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/The+Continuous+Integration+Game+plugin) (ci-game) be used in a Jenkins pipeline as code (Jenkinsfile) job?

Comment: I would be interested in a hands-on example Jenkinsfile, if there is any.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the ci-game plugin does not (yet) support pipelines.
The plugin does not appear in the [Plugin Compatibility with Pipeline](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) list.

There's already an open ticket on this issue ([JENKINS-42683](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42683)).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the latest update 1.26 includes the DSL for ci-game (see https://github.com/jenkinsci/ci-game-plugin/pull/19/commits/89e6c3e6ff11294418c2e741ebade5cfaa53ba1d
)

I tested it out and it seems to work when you put ciGame() :

```
post {
  always {
    ciGame()
  }
}
```

However, this writer complained that it doesn't work:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/ci-game-plugin/commit/89e6c3e6ff11294418c2e741ebade5cfaa53ba1d

Answer (score -1):

Simple Jenkins declarative pipeline with single Stage

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello world!' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simple Jenkins declarative pipeline with multiple Stage

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                echo 'Inside Stage 1' 
            }
        }
       stage('Stage 2') {
            steps {
                echo 'Inside Stage 2' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simple Jenkins declarative pipeline with Post Actions

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                echo 'Inside Stage 1' 
            }
        post {
            failure {
                 script { echo 'failure Inside Stage 1'  }

            }
        success {
             script { echo 'failure Inside Stage 1'  }

        }
      }
    }
   stage('Stage 2') {
        steps {
            echo 'Inside Stage 2' 
        }
       post {
          failure {
              script { echo 'failure Inside Stage 2'  }

          }
          success {
              script { echo 'failure Inside Stage 1'  } 
          }
        }
    }
}
```

https://devopsdiagnosis.wixsite.com/tech/forum/jenkins/jenkins-pipeline

Comment: this question is about using the ciGame plugin in declarative pipeline